# input.read() func. lock in the while loop

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

After connecting to server, I run some commands on server and then trying to take the server knowledge to console with;

```
while(i!=-1){
                String c="";
                String line = "";

                    try {
                        while ((i = input.read()) != 10 && i!=-1) {
                            bx[0] = (byte) i;
                            c = new String(bx);
                            line = line + c ;
                            System.out.print(c);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                    File outfile = new File("calltrak.txt");
                    boolean append = true;
                    try
                    {
                        if (!outfile.exists())
                        {
                            append = false;
                        }
                        FileWriter fout1 = new FileWriter("calltrak.txt",append);
                        PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(fout1,true);
                        fileout.println(line);
                        fileout.flush();
                        fileout.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    disp.append(line);
            }
```

But the problem is when the program read all lines from server windows, in server it waits to new input and my prog still tring to read the line and so it locked... How can I solve this problem... (Note:Using a timer isn't a way to solve because the lines which the program read can be 100 line or 100000 and sometimes server can work slow) (In the code "disp" is Jpanel name)

Comment: There's `BufferedReader` for reading characters and lines from a stream.

Comment: BufferedReader cause the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with using paralel thread. With starting Inputstream read method I also started another thread and put inside of it a timer.If read method wait more than 5 seconds, other thread sen -1 to first loop and so loop terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems performance wise with your code, but to answer your question you should let the server send a EndOfText 0x3 or EndOfTransmission 0x4 at the end see [AsciiTable](http://www.asciitable.com/) this way you can terminate then.